# Tag synonym: working-from-home <--> remote

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I'd suggest merging the [working-from-home](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/working-from-home) tag into the [remote](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote) tag (as a tag synonym) since they pretty much cover the same topic.

Comment: I'm going to suggest *against* this, simply because they mean two different things in a majority of the questions I see.

Comment: @CanadianLuke can you take a look at the suggested edits I made to the tags? They've been pending for over a week now.

Answer (score 4):

I'd argue against it, and here's why:

- [working-from-home](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/working-from-home) implies that the regular base of operations is at the worker's home. This does have its own set of problems (such as logistics with family, home office tax write-offs, etc.)
- [remote](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote) implies that the base of operations is anywhere other than the client's office. While this includes working at home, it also covers working from Starbucks (or your local coffee shop), a co-op, or other places.

While I understand your point of view (and at face value, both seem pretty similar), they've been used in different ways thus far, so they shouldn't be marked as synonyms.

Comment: Fair enough. I would then suggest someone with the appropriate permissions to include an informative description for each tag (currently only the remote tag has a summary) that allows people to understand this distinction. And perhaps add a reference (link, if possible) to each other, for those who search for one term meaning the other.

Comment: @waldyrious - Great news; all users can suggest tag edits, so if you'd like to, feel free to do such! I don't have the particular permission set to approve/reject tag edits, but I know the mods and people with higher reputation can approve/reject such edits.

Comment: I made suggested edits to both tags, please check them out (if your permissions allow you to see edit suggestions) and let me know what you think :)